# Python pygal rendering to screen

Tags: python, plot, graph, pygal

I am following a book (Python Crash Course) and I am not able to see the plot. This is my code

```
from pygal.maps.world import World
wm  = World()
wm.title = "Population of Countries in North America"
wm.add('North America', { 'ca':34126000, 'us': 309349000, 'mx': 113423000})
#wm.render_to_file('na_populations.svg')
wm.render()
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I am trying this out on SublimeText.

Comment: don't you get any error when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? What do you find in documentation - maybe it need something more - it may render to file and you have to manually open it in browser.

Comment: I tested code and it is used only to render to file which you have to open manually, or as text with SVG which you can use in own HTML - but this HTML you have to also open manually. Eventually you can use `import webbrowser` and `webbrowser.open('na_populations.svg')` to open it with default program for file .svg - it can be web browser but it depends what settings use system (Windows, Linux, MacOS)

Comment: see pygal doc [output](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html) - there is `render_in_browser()` - but if system has assigned `.svg` to other program then web browser (ie. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)) then it opens in other program.